# Group by a collection as the key

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this kind of class :

```
public class EntityIdentifier
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int EntityId { get; set; }
    int SourceId { get; set; }

    ICollection<BaseEntityIdentifierDetail> IdentifierValues { get; set; }
}
```

An EntityIdentifier consists of a list of keyvalue pairs (the IdentifierValues).

I then have a list of EntityIdentifier that I would like to group by the IdentifierValues property.

```
var allIds = myIdentifiers.GroupBy(i => i.IdentifierValues);
```

It compiles, but I am not sure how it will behave. My guess is I have to implement some overrides (like Equal and GetHashCode maybe) somewhere so that a list of objects can correctly be used as a grouping key.

Anyone know what to implement in order for a collection to be correctly used as a grouping key?

EDIT 1: For two EntityIdentifiers to be equal, their key-value pairs (IdentifierValues) must all be identical. E.g. all the same keys associated with same values and the lists of the same size.

EDIT 2: Code for the IdentifierValues:

```
public class BaseEntityIdentifierDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, what defines "equality" for your collections?  All items are the same?  Does order matter?

Comment: @DStanley good question, equality between 2 EntityIdentifiers is when their key-value pairs (IdentifierValues) are the same. E.g. same keys with same values

Comment: Can you post the code for `IdentifierValues` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably implement the [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132155(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.  Then use the [`GroupBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334(v=vs.100).aspx) method that uses the `IEqualityComparer<T>` class defined.

```
public class ColectionBaseEntityIdentifierDetailComparer 
  : IEqualityComparer<ICollection<BaseEntityIdentifierDetail>>
{
    public bool Equals(ICollection<BaseEntityIdentifierDetail> left,
      ICollection<BaseEntityIdentifierDetail> right)
    {
        // compare left and right
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ICollection<BaseEntityIdentifierDetail> obj)
    {
        // return correctly implemented GetHashCode()
        return 1; 
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    var a = new List<EntityIdentifier>();

    var b = a.GroupBy(ei => ei.IdentifierValues, 
      new ColectionBaseEntityIdentifierDetailComparer());
```

Comment: perfect :) is GetHashCode method anyhow relevant in terms of GroupBy?

Comment: [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)

Comment: I thought I've just asked you that... why is it important to override it and return 1?

Comment: Was my comment directly above that line not enough information?

Comment: If it was I wouldn't ask.